# PostGresql Not Creating minimum pool size connection

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, connection-pooling, pool

when I connect to sql server and I have minimum pool size for example 10(Min Pool Size=0;) it will show me 10 connection in sql after executing this query

> select * From sys.dm_exec_connections

but in postgresql I have putted (Minimum Pool Size=10) and it always Add one connection after executing this query

> SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity where usename = "userName"

so how to make postgres create minimum pool size connection while connecting to it from my C# project.

NB: I am using Npgsql(5.0.7) NuGet package

Comment: Your question seems to about the behavior of a specific connection pooler.  But you don't say what that is.  (NuGet doesn't seem to be a connection pooler)

Comment: My questions is that when I connect to the database and I have pooling in  my connection string I can't see minimum pool Size connection created in postgresql using this query (SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity where usename = "userName"). for example if I have minimum pool Size 10 it should create 10 connection when I connect to the Db but it always show 1 connection 
and I have experiment this in sql server before it always create minimum pool size and I can see it using this query (select * From sys.dm_exec_connections)

Answer (score 1):

As the doc says :

*"PostgreSQL also supports reporting of the exact command currently being executed by other server processes"*

"*other server processes*" means that the current connection is not viewed by this query...

This is not live like SQL Server....

Comment: please can you provide the link of this document. Thank you

Comment: and is their any way to view all connections

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/monitoring-stats.html and no...